# Linux Game Development Resources

Tags: linux

Do you have any Linux-specific game development resources?

Comment: Do you mean resources for developing on Linux, or resources for developing games that run on Linux?

Comment: Question is very vague. Ask more precisely what you want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender might be worth checking out, both for asset creation and for the game engine it offers.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not much of a Linux guy, but these are my recommendations based on research and experience:

**Programming**

- Eclipse IDE for code editing and project management.
- Java.
- GCC.
- Python.
- OpenGL.

**Programming Libraries**

- Java2D.
- SDL.
- PyGame.
- Allegro.

**Art**

- The Gimp (bitmap).
- Inkscape (vector graphics).
- Blender (3D).

**Sound**

- Audacity.
- LMMS (Linux Multimedia Studio).

Comment: Ardour which is a digital audio workstation is worth taking a look at as far as sound goes

Comment: @Steve Ardour has certainly come a long way since the last time I had a look at it. Not quite what I am after as the MIDI stuff is lacking compared to Apple Logic Studio, but not bad all the same.